# How to input HTML code of yandex

Tags: performance

Recently I've opened a website for a glider company. Glidr is the product they sell which is a personal transporter. I've linked it with bing, but I don't know how to submit it. Can you tell me the process for submitting my site [www.myglider.com](http://www.myglider.com) to yandex? Also tell me the process to make a android apps for this site please